# Full screen modal in materialize design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am using Materialize design. And i am implementing full screen modal. Width is spend in full screen but height is not set in full screen. I have seen one link then i want to implement like this. If any plugin and any other solution, Then let me know.
http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
   
  </div>
```

I don't want to same as link(animation). But i want to implement opened modal cover full screen.

Answer (score 2):

In materialize.css file, I looked into `.modal` selector and it has a property called `max-height: 70%;` that's why your inline style height: 100% was not working. You can override the default `max-height`.

**CSS**

```
.modal {
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

**PICTURE**

[image]

**DEMO**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/3zogjaw7/4/)